# htaccess rules for domain mapping and preserve current configuration

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dns

I have a site with dynamic subdomains based on registered usernames that are parsed using php and for that my htaccess works without a problem.
Here are some example on how the redirect works from $_SERVER

thecspace.com/blogs

```
["QUERY_STRING"]          => string(21) "template=www&q=blogs/"
```

http://www.thecspace.com/blogs/test-pp-blog-2904

```
["QUERY_STRING"]          => string(38) "template=www&q=blogs/test-pp-blog-2904"
```

http://danvlad.thecspace.com/blogs/test-pp-blog-2904

```
["QUERY_STRING"]          => string(47) "template=danvlad&q=blogs/test-pp-blog-2904"
```

CURRENT HTACCESS

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thecspace\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.thecspace.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^\.]+)?\.thecspace\.com
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?template=%2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^\.]+)?\.thecspace\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule (.*) index.php?template=%2&q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Now comes the hard part. I want to allow custom domains to use the same rules. Let's say devdemogroup have the domain devdemogroup.com. Once they change DNS to point to domain.com I want to be able to allow that domain to use current code from domain.com

So, in theory a request to www.danvlad.com would be a this query string

```
["QUERY_STRING"]          => string(47) "template=danvlad"
```

and www.danvlad.com/blogs/

```
["QUERY_STRING"]          => string(47) "template=danvlad&q=blogs"
```

I've tried this but it won't work

```
RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.thecspace\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}   ^([^.]+)\.thecspace\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule   ^$ /index.php?template=%1 [L]

RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.thecspace\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}   ^www\.([^.]+)\.thecspace\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule   ^$ /index.php?template=%1 [L]

RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.thecspace\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}   ^www\.([^.]+)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule   ^$ /index.php?template=%1 [L]

RewriteRule   ^(.*)$ /index.php?template=%1?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Can anyone help?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Actually your last `RewriteRule` is without conditions, use it like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.thecspace\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?([^.]+)\.thecspace\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?template=%1?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: devdemogroup.thecspace.com/blogs now redirects to www.thecspace.com
and devdemogroup.com doesn't set template to devdemogroup

Comment: 1. I don't have any REDIRECT flag so it cannot redirect, check other rules and clear browser cache. My rule is only internally rewriting to `/index.php?template=%1?q=$1` which cannot redirect. 2. You have used `www.devdemogroup.com`, `www.domin.com` and `devdemogroup.thecspace.com` in your question. Which one is correct? Is `devdemogroup` starting part or middle part?

Comment: thecspace.com = domain.com (I forgot to edit in initial post)
Let me double check and exit before a redirect
devdemogroup.com - no template
http://www.thecspace.com/blogs/ - not found
http://devdemogroup.thecspace.com/ - template = devdemogroup

Comment: Revised initial post, fixed domain names to clear out any confusion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64309/discussion-between-ovidiu-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 0):

Final solution

Route53
thecspace.com Zone
danvlad .thecspace.com CNAME www.thecspace.com
www.danvlad .thecspace.com CNAME www.thecspace.com

danvlad Zone
www.danvlad.com CNAME www.thecspace.com

Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all
    DirectoryIndex index.php

```
# Redirect thecspace.com and cspace.thecspace.com to www.thecspace.com

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thecspace\.com$ [NC] [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_POST} ^cspace.thecspace.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.thecspace.com/$1 [R,L,QSA]

# Redirect abc.thecspace.com to www.thecspace.com/index.php?template=abc&q=zzz

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.thecspace\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.thecspace\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?template=%1&q=$1 [L]

# Redirect www.abc.thecspace.com to www.thecspace.com/index.php?template=abc&q=zzz

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.thecspace\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^.]+)\.thecspace\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?template=%1&q=$1 [L]

# Redirect www.abc.com to www.thecspace.com/index.php?template=abc&q=zzz

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.thecspace\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^.]+)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?template=%1&q=$1 [L]

# Redirect www.thecspace.com

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME) !^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

Maybe it helps someone.